# Audio Conversion(MP3 to PCM) in Swift

Tags: swift, core-audio, ios8

I am working on porting streaming audio player to swift. i need to conver the MP3 streaming audio in to PCM buffer before play it with AVAudioEngine. I observed that MP3 to PCM converter function(**AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer**) is missing in Swift.

How to write the code in swift to do the audio Conversion?

Comment: I don't think `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer()` is missing. I did find its declaration in a minute.

Comment: @mmcdole I found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. If I am not mistaken what you are looking for can be found here:

[Unable to convert mp3 into PCM using AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer in AudioFileStreamOpen's AudioFileStream_PacketsProc callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481608/unable-to-convert-mp3-into-pcm-using-audioconverterfillcomplexbuffer-in-audiofil)

Did you see this line:

`AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverterRef, AudioConverter_Callback, &convertInfo, &framesToDecode, &localPcmBufferList, nil)`

That person seems to have achieved exactly what you are trying to achieve.